# 520 Error On Flow From Outlook 365 to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, microsoft-flow

I have this flow that takes an attachment received via email and creates a new file on SharePoint . The flow works for smaller reports, but with a larger report I'm receiving (41MB), I am receiving a 520 error.  I receive this report daily, and would love to automate the publishing of the report to SharePoint. Has anyone resolved this issue?  Thank you.

{
  "Message": "API Hub token exchange internal server failure.",
  "SourceUri": "https://power-te-northeurope-3.azurewebsites.net//exchange",
  "IsCachedResponse": "false"
}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug for MS Flow currently, you can find the similar topic in the following thread.
[Error 520 - API Hub token exchange internal server failure](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/I-Found-A-Bug/Error-520-API-Hub-token-exchange-internal-server-failure/td-p/314576)

If it is urgent to your business, I suggest you open a ticket from Microsoft.